# Extend protocol defined in another namespace in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have this protocol defined in namespace x:

```
(ns x
  (:require [..]))

(defrecord MyData [something something-else])


(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (my-fn [data]))
```

Now I want to create an implementation of this protocol in another namespace. I've tried doing something like this:

```
(ns y
  (:require [..])
  (:import (x MyData MyProtocol)))

(extend-protocol MyProtocol
  MyData
  (my-fn [data]
    ; Do something with the data
    ))
```

However when I try to execute `my-fn` like this (from my test case):

```
(ns y-test
  (:require [x :refer [MyData my-fn]]
            [...]))

...

(let [data (->MyData ...)]
    (my-fn data))
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :my-fn of protocol: #'x/MyProtocol found for class: x.MyData
```

If I move `MyProtocol` to namespace `y` it seem to work. What am I missing?

**Update**

After ayato_p's answer I required the Protocol (in y) instead of importing it but I still get the same error. Moving `extend-protocol` from `y` to `x` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` is just for Java classes, so you can't import `MyProtocol` by `:import`.

Following code works with your record type and protocol.

```
(ns y
  (:require [.. Myprotocol])
  (:import (x MyData)))
```

Comment: I've tried that now but it still gives me the same error :/

Comment: Ah, I see. Also you need to `require` namespace `y` in the `y-test` namespace.